# Reading a File "changes" my path and FXMLLoader fails

Tags: javafx-8, fxml

I've been struggling with my code:

```
    private void longStart() {
    Task task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Iniciando");
            IOManager io = new IOManager();
            System.out.println("Buscando archivo Jugadores");
            boolean b = io.BuscarData("Jugadores");
            System.out.println("Armando Grupos");
            if (!b) {
                ServiceManager.CargarGrupos(b);
            } else {
                if (!io.BuscarData("Grupos")) {
                    ServiceManager.CargarGrupos(b);
                }else{
                    Grupo.setaGrupos(io.LeerGrupos());  
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Cargando Partidos");
            ServiceManager.CargarPartidos();
            System.out.println("Calculando puntos de Grupos");
            ServiceManager.ActualizarPuntos();
            //ServiceManager.CargarGoleador();
            ready.setValue(Boolean.TRUE);
            notifyPreloader(new StateChangeNotification(StateChangeNotification.Type.BEFORE_START));
            return null;
        }
    };
    new Thread(task).start();
}
```

To put it simply, what it does is to ask if a file exists and if it doesn't, then it connects with a web service, does some meaningless object creations and finally creates the File. After all that hustle I can start my UI like this:

```
    try {
                    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Main.fxml"));
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Brasuca.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                stage.setTitle("Brasil 2014");
                stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1140, 705));
                stage.getIcons().add(new Image("/img/trophy.png"));
                stage.setResizable(false);
                stage.show();
```

Which works perfectly when the File its looking for doesn't exist. But when it does Exists it tries to read it:

```
    public ArrayList<Grupo> LeerGrupos() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ArrayList<Grupo> ag;
    try (ObjectInputStream obj = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("data/Grupos.jug"))) {
        ag = (ArrayList<Grupo>) obj.readObject();
    }
    return ag;
}
```

Which also works fine, but when the FXMLLoader tries to load, it fails and throws this exception:

```
    GRAVE: null
    javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
    file:/C:/Users/Francisco/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Brasuca/dist/run613176200/Brasuca.jar!/fxml/Main.fxm
```

Also, if I excecute the loader like this:

```
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/Main.fxml"));
```

The exception changes into:

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
```

Any help would be apretiated

Answer (score 0):

```
root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Main.fxml"));
```

Don't forget the "/" when you try to load fxml class because of it is another package.